# Use a framework functions without importing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created 2 frameworks. One for Chat App UI and another one for Voice and Video Call. UI framework uses Voice framework if voice video module is enabled. If someone has disabled it, I don't want to include it, but I have already used 'import VoiceVideo' to import it into UI framework. So during build it will crash as it will not able to found it.

So my question is can we use functions of a framework without importing it by means of bundle paths or any other way.

I Have tried to create instance of VoiceVideo framework class using "NSClassFromString".

```swift
if let bundle = Bundle.init(identifier: "FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER"){
    let bundlePath = bundle.bundlePath
    let newBundle = Bundle.init(path: bundlePath)
    newBundle?.load()
    let newclass : AnyClass? = newBundle?.classNamed("ChVoiceVideo")
}
```

But it return nil.